# Intervals and cumulative probability

Tags: probability

This 2 question is about intervals, can anyone tell me how to calculate this 2 questions by Rstudio?

> Q1 [image: Q1]

---

> Q2 [image: Q2]

Comment: It looks like you need to work with a normal distribution table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to express the probability you seek in terms of $\mathsf P(X\leqslant x_1)$ and $\mathsf P(X\geqslant x_2)$ etc, when $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma)$, and rearrange in terms of $\mathsf P(Z\leqslant \tfrac{x_1-\mu}{\sigma})$ and $\mathsf P(Z\geqslant \tfrac{x_2-\mu}{\sigma})$ where $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$.   Then use your $z-$tables to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find your "z-scores"

If the distribution is normal, with a mean of 180 and a standard distribution of 10.

185 would correspond to a z-score of $\frac {185 - 180}{10} = \frac 12$

and 175 would correspond to a z-score of $\frac {185 - 180}{10} = -\frac 12$

Then you are going to need to look up the probabilities associated with those z-scores.  You can pull these off of a table, or use a calculator or a tool like MS Excel.

When you look these up the number you will get is the probability your random variable is less than or equal to 185 and 175 respectively.

But you wan less than 175 or greater than 185.

In Excel the formula would be +NORMSDIST(-0.5) - NORMSDIST(0.5)

It is worth noting that +NORMSDIST(-0.5) + NORMSDIST(0.5) = 1 due to the symmetry of the normal distribution.  So, +2*NORMSDIST(-0.5) would give the same result.

For the second problem, you would find the z-scores similarly.  But, now you want greater than 173 and less than 183.  What does that do to the algebra?